# How breadcrumb can remember the path?

Tags: angularjs, breadcrumbs

I have breadcrumbs implemented on three states below,From Dashboard user can select a process that will navigate to `edit.process` and then user can also come back from Edit Process to Dashboard using breadcrumb hyperlink. So here is the issue when user in `app.search` state he can select process that will navigate to `edit.process` state Now here user has only option to go back to Dashboard.But I want to implement logic when user is navigating process from `app.search` state i want to show app.search breadcrumb hyperlink on `edit.process` state so user can go back where he is coming from...

app.js

```
.state('app.home', {
            url: '/',
            templateUrl: 'views/riskHomePage/riskAssesmentHomePage.html',
            controller: 'HomeCtrl',
            data: {
                authenticate: true
            },
            breadcrumb: {
              title: 'Dashboard',
              path: ['app.home']
          }
        })

   .state('app.editProcess', {
            url: '/process/:processId/:refresh?:from',
            templateUrl: 'views/process/createEditProcessContent.html',
            controller: 'ProcessCtrl',
            data: {
                authenticate: true
            },
            resolve: {
                existingProcess: function($http, $stateParams, $rootScope){
                    $rootScope.showLoader = true;
                   return $http.get('app/prcs/rest/process/'+ $stateParams.processId);
                }
            },
            breadcrumb: {
              title: 'Edit Process',
              path: ['app.home', 'app.editProcess']
          }
        })

.state('app.search', {
            url: '/viewSearchInv',
            templateUrl: 'views/viewAll/viewSearchInv.html',
            controller: 'ViewSearchInvCtrl',
            data: {
                authenticate: true
            },
            breadcrumb: {
              title: 'View Search PRC inventory',
              path: ['app.home','app.search']
            }
        })
```

Comment: this might be helpful using ncy-breadcrumb https://github.com/ncuillery/angular-breadcrumb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you would want to create a breadcrumb service and then inject it into each controller.

here is an alright tutorial http://milestone.topics.it/2014/03/angularjs-ui-router-and-breadcrumbs.html

another way that i have done this in the past is by keeping an array of breadcrumbs on $rootScope.  instantiate it like this.

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
.run(function($rootScope) {
    $rootScope.breadcrumbs = [];
 })
```

then in each controller i push the breadcrumb that will link back to that state to the breadcrumbs array.  normally my breadcrumb object has the display text and the link/ui-router state reference.

```
.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope) {
    $rootScope.breadcrumbs.push({ title: "First Breadcrumb", state: "stateName" })
})
```

then to display the breadcrumbs use ng-repeat and handle the selection of any of the breadcrumbs with an ng-click function that trims breadcrumbs to the selected breadcrumb and loads the corresponding state

Answer (score -1):

You need to use ncyBreadcrumb .This way not possible.
This link help for you
[How to use ncy-breadcrumb in child state of abstract parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30905511/how-to-use-ncy-breadcrumb-in-child-state-of-abstract-parent)